# Looking for a way to prevent my phone from installing a specific app?

Tags: installation, customization

As the title says, I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent your phone from installing an app. The method would have to be irreversible, or nearly irreversible (i.e takes significant time), not something simple (i.e parental controls). If you have any ideas please let me know, no matter how technical. For reference, the most technical android thing I've done is use adb debugging for some task on an automation app. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume by "download" you mean installing. Downloading an app just creates some Internet traffic and consumes some flash memory on your device. Additionally it is way more complicated to prevent downloading an app file than preventing to install it because there are hundreds of ways to download an app, but for installing you always need the package manager.

Comment: Yes sir, I mean installing.

Comment: Unfortunately no irreversible way to block anything as the block would be implemented in software and software can always be changed back. The only chance I see would be to use a custom ROM and to manipulate the package manger to block certain apps based on their package.name. But as I said if you are able to install a custom ROM anybody else can also do the same and therefore replace the adapted package manager back to an unlimited one.

Comment: ok, thank you for your comment. Do you know if I could block certain apps in package manager like you said, without a custom ROM? Also, for context, this is for me only. I'm trying to block an app for self-control purposes, so I'm not worried about other users on the phone or anything like that